# how to get child and parent nodes from mysql database

Tags: mysql

Initially i created table name as empdetails.

```
empdetails  CREATE TABLE `empdetails` (             
              `ID` int(9) NOT NULL,                 
              `Emp_Name` varchar(30) default NULL,  
              `Supr_ID` int(9) default NULL,        
              PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)                   
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Inserting data as :

```
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '1','Project Manager 1','0');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '2','Project Manager 2','0');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '3','Manager 1','1');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '4','Manager 2','2');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '5','Lead 1','3');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '6','Lead 2','3');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '7','Lead 3','3');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '8','Lead 4','3');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '9','Lead 5','3');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '10','Lead 6','3');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '11','Emp 1','6');
insert into `empdetails` (`ID`,`Emp Name`,`Supr ID`) values ( '12','Emp 2','7');
```

My question :

1. if i give id then it will show emp_names with any emp_names contain same id as Supr_id also recursively(this problem is for printing child nodes) .

example : if i give 1 as input then output emp_names as **Project Manager 1, Manager 1, Lead 1, Lead 2, Lead 3, Lead 4,Lead 5,Lead 6,Emp 1, Emp 2**

1. if i give id then it will show emp_names with any emp_name contain id as present emp_names Supr_id (this problem is for printing parent nodes)

example : if i give 10 as input then output emp_names as **Emp 1, Lead 2, Manager 1, Project Manager 1**

Please solve both cases....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to work with what are essentially trees in SQL, Joe Celko has written an entire [book](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334) about that theme, but there are also numerous [articles](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html) written by him about that subject.